# Retrieve Battery Discharge Rate for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, power-management

I would like to know whether or not it is possible to get information on the Battery Discharge Rate of the Blackberry via certain APIs or code snippets?

If anyone has used MeterBerry before, the information available on that app is similar to the  kind of information I'd like to show on this application.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I could find is the [DeviceInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html) -class of the API that provides the method [getBatteryLevel](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getBatteryLevel%28%29):

```
public static int getBatteryLevel()

    Retrieves the current battery level.

    Returns:
        Percentage of maximum battery level remaining.
```

Monitoring the change in level over time, you could probably try to measure the speed at which the level is decreasing.